# Windows service to save word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, windows-services

I'm working on a c# windows service that's designed to save opened word documents periodically on a google drive ..
By initializing a thread that sleeps every 5 minutes for instance :

```
   while (true)
   {
        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(AutoSave));
        th.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(300000);
   }
```

The service doesn't work , although the code is working when i put it in a separate console application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a timer that ticks every 5 minutes:

```
//Create a new timer that ticks every 5 min
var t = new System.Timers.Timer (300000);

//When a tick is elapsed
t.Elapsed+=(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) => 
{
    //Start a new task (thread) that does something
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
        AutoSave();
    });
};
//Start the timer
t.Start();
```

Comment: Do you mean that using thread as mentioned in my code is affecting the service execution ??

Comment: Well, the Thread.Sleep does not block your autosave threat but rather the current thread (e.g. UI thread), meaning that Autosave will be executed all the time. A better approach is to use a timer with an interval to determine when to execute the check. Tasks are higher level versions of threads, that are easier to use.

Comment: priceless piece of info :) thnx Steven